# Inserting a chunk of text as a value of a select menu

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I am trying to use XMLHTTPRequest to get some information from another page. It will have several `<option>`s, a variable number of them.

My thoughts were that I could get all of these options, outputted as text, and insert them wholesale into the select menu. Would this be possible? An example of what I want to do:

```
<select name="culture[]" onSubmit="formValidation()" multiple="multiple" id="cultpicklist"></select>
```

is the select menu, and then I would do something like this (pseudo-code)

txtobjfromXMLHTTPRequest would be this:

```
<option value="41" name="culture[]">testculthy</option>
<option value="47" name="culture[]">ereeevvv</option>
<option value="49" name="culture[]">yep</option>
<option value="50" name="culture[]">addanother</option>

txtObj = txtobjfromXMLHTTPRequest //to shorten what I have to write/what you have to read

document.getElementById("cultpicklist").value(txtObj)
```

Would this work? Am I on the right path? How should I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("cultpicklist").innerHTML = txtObj;
```

You should however thoroughly test this in all the browsers you support, as there are some cross browser issues with this.

...and here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5PGF6/